# Git log merge commits with more than 1 commit merged

Tags: git, git-log

I want to list merged commits in the last year. So I use this:

```
git log --reverse --since=2016-01-01 --until=2016-12-31 --merges
```

However, this brings a large number of merges and I want to list only those merges which have merged more than commit in the master branch.

The flow used in the repository is [the GitHub Flow](http://githubflow.github.io/).

Ideally, I want to be able to list merges which have merged at least N number of commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs a definition of what it means to "have merged *N* commits", because there are two obvious definitions, and I think the first obvious one is wrong, but I'm not sure the second obvious one is right.

First, let's note that a *merge commit*—these are the ones selected by `--merges`—is any commit with *two or more parents*.  This is the noun form of merge, as defined in [`gitglossary`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html).

Since the number of parents is very easily counted, we could define "a merge that merges *N* commits" as "a merge that has at least *N* - 1 parents".  All merges would then merge at least 1 commit, while a merge that merges 2 commits would have 3 parents.  Note that 3-or-more-parent merges are also called *octopus merges*.  It's trivial to find these: `git rev-list --min-parents=3 <starting-point>`, for instance.  Using `--merges` with `git log` or `git rev-list`—these are mostly the same command, with slightly different default outputs—is just shorthand for `--min-parents=2`, i.e., select only commits that are merge commits.

Presumably that's *not* what you mean, though.  This gets us to the other obvious definition, but it's, well, much less obvious.

As always, we need to start by drawing bits of a commit graph.  In a typical situation in which you would run `git merge`, you have something like this:

```
...--o--*--o--o--o      <-- main
         \
          o--o----o     <-- feature
```

You now `git checkout main` and then `git merge feature` and, if all goes well and Git can merge things on its own, you get:

```
...--o--*--o--o--o--M   <-- main
         \         /
          o--o----o     <-- feature
```

The number of commits merged, in this case, is three: there are three commits that were on `feature` that were not on `main`.  (There are many commits—starting from `*` and working leftward, every commit all the way back to the first commit ever, probably—that were on *both* branches before.  Now, the three commits that were just on `feature` are also on both branches.)

But this graph is very simple.  Here's one that's not very complicated, but not so simple either:

```
...--o--*--o   <-- main
         \
          \      o   <-- fix1
           \    / \
            o--o   o--o   <-- feature
                \ /
                 o   <-- fix2
```

where it's not obvious how many commits to count.  There are six commits that are on `feature` that are not on `main`, here, but two of them have branch names (`fix1` and `fix2`) pointing straight to them, so that there are only two commits that are only on `feature`, three commits that are on both `feature` and `fix1`, and three commits—two the same, one different—that are shared with `fix2`.  Do we count all six?  Do we count five?  Do we count just two?

In sufficiently complex graphs, there may be multiple merge bases.  In this case, `git merge` defaults to doing a *recursive merge* (the default `-s` strategy is `recursive`), which works by merging the merge base commits, making what amounts to a temporary commit of the result, and then merging using that temporary commit as the merge base.  This is the hardest case of all to handle since it's not clear whether to count the virtual merge base as a commit.

#### Assuming all of the above makes sense, here's how to count

We're given an existing merge commit *M* and asked to count how many commits it "brought in".  The simplest and easiest method to count them—which is likely to be the count you want, but consider all the above as well—is to count commits reachable from the 2nd through *P*-th parents (of the *P*-parent commit *M*), not counting commits reachable through the first parent:

```
git rev-list --count M^@ ^M^1
```

This uses [`gitrevisions` syntax](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) to select all parents of commit `M`:

> **Other `<rev>^` Parent Shorthand Notations**
>    Two other shorthands exist, particularly useful for merge commits, for
>    naming a set that is formed by a commit and its parent commits.
>
> The `r1^@` notation means all parents of `r1`.  [snip]

We thus ask `git rev-list` to find all commits reachable from all parents, excluding all commits reachable from the first parent.  (It's not necessary to exclude, from the first argument, the second, i.e., `M^1`, set, since excluding the second set takes care of it.)  This works because `M^1`, the first parent of `M`, is always the commit that was on the branch before you ran `git merge`.  Hence the commits brought in via parents 2-through-*P* are counted, along with all of their ancestors that were not already on the branch at the time.

(For my first diagram, the count would be 3, and for my second, it would be 6.  If these are *not* the counts you want, you will have to refine your question.)

Put this `git rev-list --count` step in a script that you run on commit IDs obtained from `git rev-list --merges --since ... --until ...`, and select those where the resulting counts are at least your chosen limit.  Feed the final list of commit hashes to `git log --no-walk --stdin` to view them.